# Duplicate validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

If I have more than one asp.net server validator on the same control,
(Suppose that both of them can return false in a specific situation) and I want to display only one message (Except the validation summary),
How can I Achieve this goal and group the `Text` property of all the validators that link to the same control?

If I Implement this situation I receive in the output the `Text` attribute of each one of the validators...

Comment: Try writing a custom validator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put these two validators control in seperated `ValidationGroup` and create a new Custom Validator that checks these two validators controls with unified message.

```
protected void CustomValidator (object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = validator1.IsValid && validator2.IsValid
}
```

Comment: But if I put them in seperate `ValidationGroup`,  the IsValid of one of them will not be relevant because he will be in diffrenet `ValidationGroup` from the control that fire the event...

Comment: Maybe I can put the, in the same `ValidationGroup` but leave the Text Empty, and in the CustomControl leave the ErrorMessage empty, and put only the Text I want to display...

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain it with javascript function and put it in CustomeValidator & set the Text msg in customeValidator

```
function ValidateTwoValidations(oSrc, args) {
  var Val1 = document.getElementById("Validator1ClientId");
  var Val2 = document.getElementById("Validator2ClientId");

  if (Val1.IsValid = false  && Val2.IsValid = false){
      args.IsValid = false;
      }
   else {
       args.IsValid = true;
            }
 }
```